# What’s a good microprocessor/microcontroller and camera that has enough power and resolution for image processing videos of cars in a parking lot?

Tags: video-camera, embedded-systems

Basically I want to create a camera device that will monitor a parking lot and using image processing will be able to detect if the slots in the parking lot has a car or not.

I already have a code in Python that detects if there is a car in a parking lot slot. The code basically crops the slot, uses edge detection, and from there counts the amount of whiteness in an image.

I just need some recommendations on what hardware and camera  to use.